# Regex to parse queries with quoted substrings and return nested lists of individual words

Tags: python, regex, parsing, substring, quotes

I'm trying to write a regex that takes in a string of words containing quoted substrings like `"green lizards" like to sit "in the sun"`, tokenizes it into words and quoted substrings (using either single or double quotes) separated by spaces, and then returns a list `[['green', 'lizards'], 'like', 'to', 'sit', ['in', 'the', 'sun']]` where the list items are either single words or nested lists of words where a quoted substrings was encountered.

I am new to regex, and was able to find a solution that captures the quoted parts: `re.findall('"([^"]*)"', '"green lizards" like to sit "in the sun"')` ... which returns:  `['green lizards', 'in the sun']`

But this doesn't capture the individual words, and also doesn't tokenize them (returning a single string instead of list of words, which requires me to `split()` them each separately.

How would I make a regex that correctly returns the type of list I'm wanting? Also, I'm open to better methods/tools than regex for parsing these sorts of strings if anyone has suggestions.

Thanks!

Comment: Try https://ideone.com/0DwXvP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `re.findall()` function and built-in `str` methods:

```
import re

s = '"green lizards" like to sit "in the sun"'
result = [i.replace('"', "").split() if i.startswith('"') else i
          for i in re.findall(r'"[^"]+"|\S+', s)]

print(result)
```

The output:

```
[['green', 'lizards'], 'like', 'to', 'sit', ['in', 'the', 'sun']]
```

Comment: I like your solution the best, because I didn't even need an explanation to understand what it was doing. The other answers appear to work correctly as well, and might possibly be more efficient (don't know - haven't tested it), but they are more complicated, and harder for me to understand. Given that I'm only parsing relatively short search queries rather than huge volumes of text, simplicity/clarity matter more to me here than efficiency. Also, I didn't realize I could use `if` statements the way you did there, inside of a list comprehension, so bonus points for teaching me that too :)

Answer (score 2):

Another approach (supporting both single and double quotes):

```
import re

sentence = """"green lizards" like to sit "in the sun" and 'single quotes' remain alone"""

rx = re.compile(r"""(['"])(.*?)\1|\S+""")

tokens = [m.group(2).split() 
            if m.group(2) else m.group(0) 
            for m in rx.finditer(sentence)]
print(tokens)
```

Yielding

```
[['green', 'lizards'], 'like', 'to', 'sit', ['in', 'the', 'sun'], 'and', ['single', 'quotes'], 'remain', 'alone']
```

---

The idea here is:

```
(['"]) # capture a single or a double quote
(.*?)  # 0+ characters lazily
\1     # up to the same type of quote previously captured
|      # ...or...
\S+    # not a whitespace
```

In the list comprehension we check which condition was met.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `re.split` and then a final `str.split`:

```
import re
s = '"green lizards" like to sit "in the sun"'
new_s = [[i[1:-1].split()] if i.startswith('"') else i.split() for i in re.split('(?<=")\s|\s(?=")', s)]
last_result = [i for b in new_s for i in b]
```

Output:

```
[['green', 'lizards'], 'like', 'to', 'sit', ['in', 'the', 'sun']]
```

Comment: Thanks ajax1234! I'm curious about the downvote too, because your answer seems to return the correct result.  I'd be interested though to see some explanation of how this works, and some comparisons to other methods listed here, all of which also return correct result. Any reason why you'd recommend this particular method over the others?

Comment: @J.Taylor Glad to help! The answer uses `re.split` to break the original string into to groups encapsulated by `""` and those that are not. Then, an additional split is applied, however, for strings that are surrounded by quotes, the split value is placed in an additional list. That way, when flattening, quoted values will be stored in a sublist. This answer is not inherently better than the others posted, however, you will have to choose which will work best for you later in your program or other problems